# Which shell is used in GNU Make files?

Tags: make

I've seen things like `echo`, `mv`, `if`, `for`, in makefile rules.  Some kind of shell commands seem to be recognized.  Is this bash?  How can I figure out which shell is being used and full list of keywords available to me?

Comment: I always figured it was the system/user default shell, whatever that is.  Haven't seen the docs or anything though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[It's `sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_03):

> The execution line shall then be executed by a shell as if it were
>   passed as the argument to the [system()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) interface

`system()` uses `sh`. You can definitely use the keywords of the [POSIX Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), and any non-keyword commands that you expect to be available on your host platform.

`sh` on your system may actually be another name for a different shell (like `bash`), in which case you'd have more options available. That sort of makefile won't be portable, though.

As you ask about GNU make specifically, I'll also note that it permits you to [specify a different shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html) to use in the makefile, but that makefile again won't be portable to other implementations of `make`. GNU make uses `sh` by default, as POSIX specifies.

Comment: I just tested, and it appears that under GNU make, if the command contains no shell metacharacters, it's executed directly, with no shell at all!

Comment: @ it is the words “as if” that are important. The spec is about behaviour (semantics), not about implementation.

Comment: A comment only for running GoW make on Windows:
- The default SHELL in windows is usually cmd.exe
- In Windows SHELL environment variable might be set outside makefile thus altering the makefile behavior
- It is recommended to add "SHELL = cmd.exe" or similar in the beginning of makefile to force a known shell syntax for the execution of the makefile

Comment: Hey Michael, what exactly is that documentation that you've linked for `sh`? When talking about Linux stuff, it is very common for me to see somebody linking a doc and I do not understand what exactly is that documentation. Is it official documentation for make, for sh, or else? I'm trying to understand what exactly I'm reading there.

Answer (score 6):

You should also look at [PolyGlot Makefiles](http://agdr.org/2020/05/14/Polyglot-Makefiles.html), a short note on selecting the shell for particular makefile targets.

Here's selecting bash for a target named bash:

```
.ONESHELL:
bash: SHELL := bash
bash:
    # note: the double dollar-sign is required because Make substitues $variables
    export greeting="¡hola"
    echo "$${greeting}, bash!"
```

And this is just showing off:

```
.ONESHELL:
python: SHELL := python3
python:
    greeting = "hello"
    print(f"{greeting}, python!")
```

So, `make python` then prints 'hello, python!'.

Answer (score 2):

@Michael (+1) said it all (and gave pointers for the details).
Nevertheless I will emphasize a pair of details (please correct me):

1. make actions uses "sh"
2. if useful in gnumake we can redefine shell

   SHELL = bash

and use bash tricks.

3. (in a unix based environment) -- `mv`, `echo` are commands (we can use them in any shell) `if` and `for` are sh/bash depend.
4. shells have a different behavior in respect to quotations, (and also
   globs and var expansions...)
   and `make` also has some peculiar behavior about them.
5. in windows, etc, together with the installation of gnumake
   command, it may be useful to install some sort of a Unix surviving kit
   (sh / bash, some filters, fileutils, and the commands you normally use in make actions)

Comment: Could you elaborate on `and use bash tricks`? What exactly are bash tricks?